# What happens to my Service Account if my google account is deleted/deactivated

Tags: google-api, google-sites, google-account, google-developers-console

One of our customer has a Google Enterprise Account (G Suite).
We have developed an application on Google Site that use a Spread Sheet.
We have created a project in the google developer console to access the Spread Sheet form the Api and created a Service Account for this project.
Everything was created with our account (provided by the customer).
At some point our account can be deleted or deactivated by the customer.

What happens then? 
Will the project be deleted/deactivated?
Will the data in the drive be lost?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an account on Google developer console is deleted then yes all the projects and clients associated with that account will stop working.

I am not sure i understand where this sheet is located.  If the sheet is on the service accounts google drive account then yes you will loose that as well.

Once a user is deleted or deactivated anything that the account contained is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the sheet is located in the user drive. We used the same account to create the Sheet and the Service Account in the Google developer console.
The only solution I see to prevent this issue, is to ask our Customer to create "a permanent' user account and to move the Sheet and the Project to it.

Comment: No for you to create your own account.  They should not be sharing their service account credentials with you its actually against the terms of service they signed when they created the credentials.